Dio didn't catch ERROR Flutter, with dio 5.4.3+1
I want to fetch some data to list using dio get. In Flutter that wraps a getX controller.
Here is the code that has a problem. I have tried many ways, like
using DioExceptionType to catch the specific problem, and using DioException.statuscode. However, the error still cannot be caught.
class JemaatController extends GetxController {
  RxList<JemaatJSON> jemaat = RxList();
  RxBool isListViewScrollToTheDown = false.obs;
  RxBool isLoading = true.obs;
  RxBool isInternetConnect = true.obs;
  final deviceStorage = GetStorage();
  var url = "${ConfigBack.apiAdress}/admin/jemaat/";
  var itemController = ItemScrollController();

  getJemaat() async {
    var response = await DioService().getMethod(url);
    isLoading.value = true;

    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        response.data.forEach((element) {
          jemaat.add(JemaatJSON.fromJson(element));
        });
      }
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        isLoading.value = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      isLoading.value = false;
      if (e is DioException) {
        if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
          FilemonHelperFunctions.showSnackBar(
              "Waktu sesi telah berakhir silahkan Re-Log");
          deviceStorage.write('user_login', false);
          deviceStorage.write('IsFirstTime', false);
          print(deviceStorage.read('user_login'));
          print(deviceStorage.read('IsFirstTime'));
          deviceStorage.remove('usertoken');
          deviceStorage.remove('userC');
          NavigationAdmin().toMain();
          if (e.type == DioExceptionType.connectionError) {
            FilemonHelperFunctions.showSnackBar(
                "Koneksi bermasalah, ini bukan pada perangkat anda");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  remJemaat() async {
    jemaat.clear();
  }

  scrollListViewDownward() {
    itemController.scrollTo(
        index: jemaat.length - 4,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
    isListViewScrollToTheDown.value = true;
  }

  /// Scroll ListView To Up
  scrollListViewUpward() {
    itemController.scrollTo(
        index: 0,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
    isListViewScrollToTheDown.value = false;
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    getJemaat();
    super.onInit();
  }
}

and for the error that I got, this is what's shown in the debug console:
E/flutter (12149): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:509:7)
E/flutter (12149): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12149): #1      DioService.getMethod.<anonymous closure> (package:MobileGKI/data/api_config.dart:102:54)
E/flutter (12149): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12149): #2      DioService.getMethod (package:MobileGKI/data/api_config.dart:102:12)
E/flutter (12149): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12149): #3      JemaatController.getJemaat (package:MobileGKI/data/crud_state/jemaat/jemaatlisting.dart:26:20)
E/flutter (12149): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12149): 

The dio get method is used here:
class DioService {
  Future<dynamic> getMethod(String url) async {
    dioUpers.Dio dio = dioUpers.Dio();
    dioUpers.Options options =
        dioUpers.Options(headers: HeadersCode().data(), method: "GET");
    return await dio.get(url, options: options).then((response) {
      return response;
    });
  }`

Don't worry about one of '}' on DioService, is not the whole script.
and for the header
class HeadersCode {
  final deviceStorage = GetStorage();
  data() {
    Map<String, dynamic> headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${deviceStorage.read("usertoken")}',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      // Add more headers if needed
    };
    return headers;
  }
}

How can I catch the error?

You need to put the call also in the try block:
try {
  var response = await DioService().getMethod(url);
  isLoading.value = true;
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    response.data.forEach((element) {
      jemaat.add(JemaatJSON.fromJson(element));
    });
  }

If something goes wrong catch block will be executed.
